# See the variable in the same method=null ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use library soap the return of this function in on nsdictionary i change it into nsarray after i close ];} and type nslog it give that nsarray =null but if i put it before close of the method in the method give data

```
- (void)showlinks
{        
    SYSoapClient *show_links_obj = [SYSoapClient new];
    links_tags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"empid", @"type", nil];
    links_vars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:txt_username, type_user, nil];
    [show_links_obj callSoapServiceWithParameters__functionName:@"getlinks" 
                                                           tags:links_tags 
                                                           vars:links_vars 
                                                       callback:^(NSDictionary *result, 
                                                                  BOOL response) 
    {
        link_raw_Data = [result allValues];
        link_con_Data = [link_raw_Data componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        //NSArray *links = [con_Data componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
        links = [link_con_Data componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@^"]];
        NSUInteger x = links.count;
        NSLog(@"%@",link_raw_Data);
        //NSLog(@"%d",x);
        //NSLog(@"%@",links[5]);
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@",links[5]);
}
```

Comment: the second nslog(@"%@",link[5]); gives null

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the callback argument to the soap service, it's an asynchronous call. This means that it will return right away, do the networking on a background thread and call the callback sometime later when it is done.

Since it's asynchronous and doesn't wait/block, the log statement just after it will be executed before getting any data back from the soap service.

Comment: That is already what is happening. If you want to run some code when the soap call finishes then you should put in in the callback (the block)